# IteratorGetNext' Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [148,118,3] and element 16 had shape [139,136,3]

Tags: python, shapes, reshape

> ```
> builder_malaria = tfds.builder("malaria")
> info = builder_malaria.info
>
> (train_ds,test_ds,val_ds),metadeta = tfds.load("malaria",
>                                                split=('train[:80%]','train[80%:90%]','train[90%:]'),
>                                                with_info=True,
>                                                as_supervised=True)
>
> num_classes = metadeta.features['label'].num_classes
>
> def normalizing(image,label):
>   # image, label = tf.reshape(image,(1,28,28,3)),tf.reshape(label,( 1))
>   return tf.cast(image,tf.float32,)/255,label
>
> AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
> train_ds = train_ds.map(normalizing,num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
> test_ds = test_ds.map(normalizing,num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
> val_ds = val_ds.map(normalizing,num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
>
> def configuration_for_performance(ds):
>   ds=ds.cache()
>   ds=ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
>   ds=ds.batch(32)
>   ds=ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
>   return ds
>
> train_ds = configuration_for_performance(train_ds)
> test_ds = configuration_for_performance(test_ds)
> val_ds = configuration_for_performance(val_ds)
>
> model = keras.Sequential([
>     # keras.layers.Resizing(200,200,input_shape=(200,200,3)),
>     # keras.layers.Input((200,200,3)),
>     keras.layers.Conv2D(32,3,padding="same",activation="relu",input_shape=(200,200,3)),
>     keras.layers.MaxPool2D(3),
>     keras.layers.Conv2D(64,3,padding="same",activation="relu"),
>     keras.layers.MaxPool2D(3),
>     keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
>     keras.layers.Flatten(),
>     keras.layers.Dense(128),
>     keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
> ])
>
> model.compile(
>     optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003),
>     loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
>     metrics=["accuracy"],
> )
> ```

> Model: "sequential_4" _________________________________________________________________  Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #    =================================================================  conv2d_8 (Conv2D)           (None, 200, 200, 32)      896                                                                           max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPooling  (None, 66, 66, 32)       0           2D)                                                                                                                                 conv2d_9 (Conv2D)           (None, 66, 66, 64)        18496                                                                         max_pooling2d_9 (MaxPooling  (None, 22, 22, 64)       0           2D)                                                                                                                                 dropout_4 (Dropout)         (None, 22, 22, 64)        0                                                                             flatten_4 (Flatten)         (None, 30976)             0                                                                             dense_8 (Dense)             (None, 128)               3965056                                                                       dense_9 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 258                                                                          ================================================================= Total params: 3,984,706 Trainable params: 3,984,706 Non-trainable params: 0   history = model.fit(train_ds,epochs=10,validation_data=val_ds)ù